# Magento 2.3 - How to move payment method list to the first step of checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

Is it possibile to move "payment method list" from 2° step checkout to the 1° step checkout? How can I do that?

Comment: Payment method list and what about billing address fill first?

Comment: @VijayKhirade both in the first step as "one step checkout"

Comment: Have you used any extension for one step checkout?

Comment: @VijayKhirade none